# Does concurrent READ/WRITE access to memory by itself cause errors/violations?

Tags: windows, concurrency, x86, x86-64

If I have a multiprocessor setup and two threads that access the same memory (let's say the same actual byte or word, not only "the same area"), does this cause errors by itself?

What if two threads are not only reading, but also writing and combining reading and writing (say, thread 1 tries to read at the same time as thread 2 is trying to write, or if both are trying to write at the same time). Will this cause an error/BSOD/AV, or is the only problem that the behaviour is undefined? (that one of the threads will get wrong data, dependent on the actual timings)

Comment: You won't break your computer, since physically there will only ever be one memory operation at a time; it's just that you cannot make any predictions what the two processes will end up reading and what the final value of the memory location will be if you don't synchronise the access.

Comment: I know the computer won't break ;), but is it possible that one of the threads (or both) will error out and exit while this happens?

Comment: No. All operations execute as normal, it's just that they're result is unpredictable.

Comment: @Cray how would the operation know this happened (assuming its not a CAS instruction)

Comment: Well I assumed there could be problems when the two processors would try to fetch or store the same memory, there would be some kind of electronic error which would cause a violation interrupt or something. But Kerrek SB says that's not the case.

Comment: Question accuracy is important.  "get wrong data" can't happen, they are writing.  Clearly nothing good will happen when the write is not atomic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) No, threads are free to read/write everywhere in program application memory. (Ok, it is possible to protect some part of memory, like program code memory to protect it.)

2) Any CPU core has own cache and data is first copied and than modified in cache line after that is copied at appropriate (unpredictable) time back to RAM. There are special cpu instruction (like lock) which must be executed together with other instruction (like cmpxchg) to ensure atomic ([interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686360%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)) RAM read, write or modify, some instructions are atomic by default.

Remember: the atomic (interlocked) RAM access can be only 1, 2, 4 or 8 (and 16 under 64bit CPU) bytes long.
For longer memory structures you must ensure corresponding locking (sinhronisation) mechanism like [Critical Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to avoid uncontroled memory access by several threads.